# How to find and replace on a specific amount of times?

Tags: shell, command-line, command

I need to find the first 413 times this is in a text file:

```
<title>Local SEO Services - The Company Review</title>
```

And replace it with this:

```
<title>Local SEO Services - TheCompany Review</title>
```

Is there a way to do this via command line and limit it only to the first 413 results?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a real basic idea implemented in Perl:

```
perl -e 'foreach (<>) { $count<2 && s/hello/goodbye/ && $count++; print; }'
```

This replaces the first two occurrences of 'hello' with 'goodbye'.  It is line-based, however.  If you have two replacements on a single line, it won't work.

Note that it operates on the standard streams, *ie* reads from stdin and writes to stdout.

You will need to escape any special characters (like `/`) like this: `\/`.  *eg*

```
s/<title>Local SEO Services - The Company Review<\/title>/<title>Local SEO Services - TheCompany Review<\/title>/
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Where do I enter the filename in that for it to know which file to run on?

Comment: Like I said, you read and write the standard streams.  So you can use file redirection: `perl -e 'etc etc' < input.txt > output.txt`